# Constrained K-means, R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means

I am currently doing k-means to cluster my data, however, I wish each cluster to appear once in each given year. I have searched for answers for a whole night but with no result. Would anyone have ideas upon this problem using R? Or is there any package I should look for ? Thanks.

More background infos :
I try to replicated the cluster of relationships, using the reported gender, education level and birth year. I am doing this because this is a survey data whose respondents are old people and they sometime will report inaccurate age or education infos. My main challenge now is that I wish to "have only one cluster labels in each survey year". For example, I do not want to see there are two cluster3 in survey year 2000. My data is like below :

| survey year | relationship | gender | education level | birth year | k-means cluster |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2000 | 41( first daughter) | 0 | 3 | 1997 | 1 |
| 2003 | 41( first daughter) | 0 | 3 | 1997 | 1 |
| 2000 | 42( second daughter) | 0 | 4 | 1999 | 2 |
| 2003 | 42( second daughter) | 0 | 4 | 1999 | 2 |
| 2000 | 42( third daughter) | 0 | 5 | 1999 | 2 |
| 2003 | 42( third daughter) | 0 | 5 | 2001 | 3 |

Thanks in advance.

--Update--

A more detailed description of the task:
The data set is a panel survey data asking elders for their health status, their relationships ( incl. sons, daughters, neighbors ). Since these older people are sometimes imprecise on their family's demographic information such as birth year, education level, etc., we might need to delete a big part of the data if it did not match.
(e.g., A reported his first son is 30 years old in 1997, while said his first son was 29 years old in 1999, this data could therefore be problematic). My task is to save as much data as possible if the imprecision is not that high.

Therefore I first mutated columns to check the precision of each family member (e.g., birth year error %in% c(-1,2)). Next, I run k-means if the family members are detected to be imprecise. In this way, I save much of the data. Although I did not solve the above problem, it rarely occurs that I can almost ignore or drop these observations.

Comment: The measurement level of you example is pretty simple. You could easily have multiple people from the same survey year who have exactly the same values. How will you decide which one(s) to remove?

Comment: I agree with @dcarlson and we need to know a bit more of what your goal is and your processing steps to help you. If you are fitting some model, it looks a logistic regression may be what you want. If you are doing some hypothesis testing, maybe a chi square test is what your looking for.

Comment: @dcarlson, Thanks for your advise, I also encounter the problem you mentioned in these two days. Instead of tickling with these simple measurement level to replicate the relationship, I put more effort on pick up  strange observations. Therefore the relations need to use k-means is less and can solve my task. Thanks!

Comment: @YuanYin Thanks for the advise! I will reframe my problem in the update part in this article. This problem is solved using other method, thanks !